# it don't work when fragment nested fragment in dagger2 dagger-android

Tags: android-fragments, dagger-2

In the `com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.11`,injector is null when a child fragment nested in parent fragment. Use `@ContributesAndroidInjector`

Comment: Can you add a working code sample to the question that reproduces your error?

Answer (score 0):

I have known it.when use FragmentPagerAdapter in dagger2-android,the getParentFragment() couldn't be null,so I must use getChildFragmentManager to the FragmentPagerAdapter.And then it works.